Flink does not subscribe to all topics if parallelism is more than 1
I am working on a Flink job that reads data from two different Pulsar topics using the Flink Pulsar connector. The job works as expected when the parallelism is set to 1. However, when I increase the parallelism to a value greater than 1, only one of the sources subscribes to its topic, while the other source does not.
This issue occurs when deploying the job using the Flink Operator on a Kubernetes cluster.
Here is how I have set up the two Pulsar sources:
PulsarSource<Object1> firstSource =
        PulsarSource.builder()
                .setConfig(PulsarSourceOptions.PULSAR_MAX_FETCH_TIME, 20L)
                .setServiceUrl(Objects.requireNonNullElse(System.getenv("PULSAR_URL"), AppConfig.PULSAR_URL_LOCAL_DEFAULT))
                .setStartCursor(StartCursor.latest())
                .setTopics(AppConfig.TOPIC1)
                .setDeserializationSchema(Schema.AVRO(Object1.class), Object1.class)
                .setSubscriptionName("Object1Subscription")
                .enableSchemaEvolution()
                .build();

PulsarSource<Object2> secondSource =
        PulsarSource.builder()
                .setConfig(PulsarSourceOptions.PULSAR_MAX_FETCH_TIME, 1000L)
                .setServiceUrl(Objects.requireNonNullElse(System.getenv("PULSAR_URL"), AppConfig.PULSAR_URL_LOCAL_DEFAULT))
                .setStartCursor(StartCursor.earliest())
                .setTopics(AppConfig.TOPIC2)
                .setDeserializationSchema(Schema.AVRO(Object2.class), Object2.class)
                .setSubscriptionName("Object2Subscription")
                .enableSchemaEvolution()
                .build();


When the parallelism is set to 1, both sources subscribe and consume data as expected.
When the parallelism is increased to 2 or more, one of the topics is not subscribed to.
The issue arises when using the Flink Operator in a Kubernetes environment.

Why does increasing the parallelism cause one of the sources to not subscribe to its topic?
Fink Version: 1.19
Flink Operator: 1.9.0
